# How to acquire the Xcode workspace path

Tags: xcode

I has tried to find answer on the dev library. I want to make a Xcode plugin need to know the current project's path,any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple plugins for Xcode that already fix the problem of finding the current project's workspace/project file.

I took a look at [Derived data exterminator](https://github.com/kattrali/deriveddata-exterminator/). Digging into the code of that plugin reveals how you can try doing this:

```
    NSArray* workspaceWindowControllers = [NSClassFromString(@"IDEWorkspaceWindowController") workspaceWindowControllers];
if (workspaceWindowControllers.count < 1)
    return nil;

id workspace = [workspaceWindowControllers[0] valueForKey:@"_workspace"];
```